# What is the difference between .getClass() and .getAttribute("class") in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Please see the below code

```
`<div class="datepicker dropdown-menu" style="display: block; top: 301px; left: 308px;">
<div class="datepicker-days" style="display: block;">
<div class="datepicker-months" style="display: none;">
<div class="datepicker-years" style="display: none;">
</div>`
```

I am trying get the classname of the Divs present inside Div with classname(datepicker dropdown-menu") but it work with 
`wdriver.getAttribute("class").toString();` and not with 
`wdriver.getclass().toString();`. Can anybody tell me what is the difference?

Comment: Show us your code for better explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There lot of diffrence between getclass() and getAttribute("class")

Let me show you with example.

First of all

getclass() - return type is webelement

getAttribute("class") - return type is string

For e.g

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1#identifier");
    Thread.sleep(4000L);
    WebElement a  = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='next']"));
    String b = a.getAttribute("class");
    System.out.println(b);
    a.getClass();
    System.out.println(a);
```

html code

```
<input id="next" class="rc-button rc-button-submit" type="submit" value="Next" name="signIn"/>
```

b will print the value of the attribute class which is 'rc-button rc-button-submit'.

While getClass() will print the xpath of it. i.e. .//*[@id='next']

Hope You can relate now why you were not getting from getClass() as return type is different. Feel free to ask for query. Happy Learning :-)

Comment: Yes, got the difference. Thanks

Comment: @Gourav : If you accept my answer just tick the answer or upvote it which is on left side where my answer begins.
Happy learning :-)

Answer (score 0):

**getClass()** : `Returns the runtime class of this(given element) Object. The returned Class object is the object that is locked by static synchronized methods of the represented class.`

**getAttribute** : `Get the value of a the given attribute of the element.`

Answer (score 0):

May be you meant like: webelement.getAttribute("class").toString() and webelement.getclass().toString() respectively.

In this case, first one gets an attribute of the webelement whereas, the second one gets the class of the given webelement.